# How to update quantity of database from php action

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

I am building a database of different devices which is displayed in a page which sells medical devices. When a user adds a quantity of the device to the cart, I want the database to be updated with (stock - quantity in cart) I am trying to do this on PHP but am having no luck. My attempt and code is below.

Here is a snippet of my attempt. I'm not sure where to place this in the code below.

```
<?php
    $value = isset($_POST['item']) ? $_POST['item'] : 1; //to be displayed
    if(isset($_POST['incqty'])){
       $value += 1;
        $query = "UPDATE products SET stock= (stock-$product_qty) WHERE product_name=$product_name";

        mysql_select_db('products');
        $retval = mysql_query($query,$mysqli);
    }

    ?>
```

This is code for index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");

//current URL of the Page. cart_update.php redirects back to this URL
$current_url = urlencode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Shopping Cart</title>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<h1 align="center">Products </h1>

<!-- View Cart Box Start -->
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"]) && count($_SESSION["cart_products"])>0)
{
    echo '<div class="cart-view-table-front" id="view-cart">';
    echo '<h3>Your Shopping Cart</h3>';
    echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php">';
    echo '<table width="100%"  cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">';
    echo '<tbody>';

    $total =0;
    $b = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm)
    {
        $product_name = $cart_itm["product_name"];
        $product_qty = $cart_itm["product_qty"];
        $product_price = $cart_itm["product_price"];
        $product_code = $cart_itm["product_code"];
        $product_color = $cart_itm["product_color"];
        $bg_color = ($b++%2==1) ? 'odd' : 'even'; //zebra stripe
        echo '<tr class="'.$bg_color.'">';
        echo '<td>Qty <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="product_qty['.$product_code.']" value="'.$product_qty.'" /></td>';
        echo '<td>'.$product_name.'</td>';
        echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="remove_code[]" value="'.$product_code.'" /> Remove</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        $subtotal = ($product_price * $product_qty);
        $total = ($total + $subtotal);
    }
    echo '<td colspan="4">';
    echo '<button type="submit">Update</button><a href="view_cart.php" class="button">Checkout</a>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';

    $current_url = urlencode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '</div>';

}
?>
<!-- View Cart Box End -->

<!-- Products List Start -->


<?php
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_code, product_name, product_desc, product_img_name, price, stock FROM products ORDER BY id ASC");
if($results){ 
$products_item = '<ul class="products">';
//fetch results set as object and output HTML
while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
{
$products_item .= <<<EOT
    <li class="product">
    <form method="post" action="cart_update.php">
    <div class="product-content"><h3>{$obj->product_name}</h3>
    <div class="product-thumb"><img src="images/{$obj->product_img_name}"></div>
    <div class="product-desc">{$obj->product_desc}</div>
    <div class="product-info">
    Price {$currency}{$obj->price} 

    <fieldset>

    <label>
        <span>Color</span>
        <select name="product_color">
        <option value="Black">Black</option>
        <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
        </select>
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Quantity</span>
        <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="product_qty" value="1" />
    </label>

    </fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="{$obj->product_code}" />


    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="{$current_url}" />





    <div align="center"><button type="submit" id="updateb" class="add_to_cart">Add</button></div>





    </div></div>
    </form>
    </li>
EOT;
}
$products_item .= '</ul>';
echo $products_item;
}
?>    
<!-- Products List End -->
</body>
</html>
```

This is code for cart_update.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");

//add product to session or create new one
if(isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"]=='add' && $_POST["product_qty"]>0)
{
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){ //add all post vars to new_product array
        $new_product[$key] = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }
    //remove unecessary vars
    unset($new_product['type']);
    unset($new_product['return_url']); 

    //we need to get product name and price from database.
    $statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT product_name, price, stock FROM products WHERE product_code=? LIMIT 1");
    $statement->bind_param('s', $new_product['product_code']);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($product_name, $price, $stock);

    while($statement->fetch()){

        //fetch product name, price from db and add to new_product array
        $new_product["product_name"] = $product_name; 
        $new_product["product_price"] = $price;
        $new_product["product_stock"] = $stock;

        if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"])){  //if session var already exist
            if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"][$new_product['product_code']])) //check item exist in products array
            {
                unset($_SESSION["cart_products"][$new_product['product_code']]); //unset old array item
            }           
        }
        $_SESSION["cart_products"][$new_product['product_code']] = $new_product; //update or create product session with new item  
    } 
}


//update or remove items 
if(isset($_POST["product_qty"]) || isset($_POST["remove_code"]))
{
    //update item quantity in product session
    if(isset($_POST["product_qty"]) && is_array($_POST["product_qty"])){



        foreach($_POST["product_qty"] as $key => $value){
            if(is_numeric($value)){

                $_SESSION["cart_products"][$key]["product_qty"] = $value; //change
            }
        }
    }
    //remove an item from product session
    if(isset($_POST["remove_code"]) && is_array($_POST["remove_code"])){
        foreach($_POST["remove_code"] as $key){
            unset($_SESSION["cart_products"][$key]);
        }   
    }
}

//back to return url
$return_url = (isset($_POST["return_url"]))?urldecode($_POST["return_url"]):''; //return url
header('Location:'.$return_url);

?>
```

This is code for view_cart.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>View shopping cart</title>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">View Cart</h1>
<div class="cart-view-table-back">
<form method="post" action="cart_update.php">
<table width="100%"  cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0"><thead><tr><th>Quantity</th><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Total</th><th>Remove</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"])) //check session var
    {
        $total = 0; //set initial total value
        $b = 0; //var for zebra stripe table 
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm)
        {
            //set variables to use in content below
            $product_name = $cart_itm["product_name"];
            $product_qty = $cart_itm["product_qty"];
            $product_price = $cart_itm["product_price"];
            $product_code = $cart_itm["product_code"];
            $product_color = $cart_itm["product_color"];
            $subtotal = ($product_price * $product_qty); //calculate Price x Qty

            $bg_color = ($b++%2==1) ? 'odd' : 'even'; //class for zebra stripe 
            echo '<tr class="'.$bg_color.'">';
            echo '<td><input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="product_qty['.$product_code.']" value="'.$product_qty.'" /></td>';
            echo '<td>'.$product_name.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$currency.$product_price.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$currency.$subtotal.'</td>';
            echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="remove_code[]" value="'.$product_code.'" /></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            $total = ($total + $subtotal); //add subtotal to total var
        }

        $grand_total = $total + $shipping_cost; //grand total including shipping cost
        foreach($taxes as $key => $value){ //list and calculate all taxes in array
                $tax_amount     = round($total * ($value / 100));
                $tax_item[$key] = $tax_amount;
                $grand_total    = $grand_total + $tax_amount;  //add tax val to grand total
        }

        $list_tax       = '';
        foreach($tax_item as $key => $value){ //List all taxes
            $list_tax .= $key. ' : '. $currency. sprintf("%01.2f", $value).'<br />';
        }
        $shipping_cost = ($shipping_cost)?'Shipping Cost : '.$currency. sprintf("%01.2f", $shipping_cost).'<br />':'';
    }
    ?>
    <tr><td colspan="5"><span style="float:right;text-align: right;"><?php echo $shipping_cost. $list_tax; ?>Amount Payable : <?php echo sprintf("%01.2f", $grand_total);?></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="5"><a href="index.php" class="button">Add More Items</a><button type="submit">Update</button></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="<?php 
$current_url = urlencode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo $current_url; ?>" />
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where are `$product_qty` and `$product_name` being defined? Also the in the query, if product_name is a string, the query is missing quotes `"UPDATE products SET stock= (stock-$product_qty) WHERE product_name='$product_name'";`

Comment: in the second code piece?

Comment: that's one of your problems, those variables don't exist in that script when it is executed

Answer (score 0):

your variables `$product_qty` and `$product_name` are not defined and in the query pass the product name in the quotes as your query is in double quotes so pass name in the single quotes.
Also it will be better if you update using primary id not by name.

Comment: how do i do this? my database columns are as follows: product_name, product_description, price, stock. do i have to create an instance variable for each of these?

Comment: what is your primary key column?